# how to upload firebase images to web using local emulator?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload some images to a firebase storage bucket,
and trying to run the code locally in the firebase emulator.

With most examples I'll get an error like:

```
  "Unhandled error FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. 
(app/no-options).    at initializeApp
```

I tried this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

```
const defaultApp = initializeApp({ credential: applicationDefault() })
```

Which may or not be working.
I *think* this creates an authed app (maybe?) but if I later use

`const storage = getStorage()` I get the same auth error.

So next, I tried using the defaultApp for next steps, like:

`const storage = defaultApp.storage();`

that doesn't error, but it returns something different from `getStorage`, that I can't seem to use for other needed things like getting a `ref`

[image]

as per examples https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

So it's not clear how to upload files to firebase from the local simulator.

my full function looks like this:

```
import cuid from "cuid";
import {
  getStorage,
  ref,
  uploadBytes,
  uploadBytesResumable,
  getDownloadURL
} from "firebase/storage";
import { admin, defaultApp } from '../utils/firebaseInit'

export function saveToBucket(url: string): string {
  const normalStorage = getStorage() // Gets a FirebaseStorage instance for the given Firebase app. but NOT AUTHED
  const defaultStorage = defaultApp.storage(); // Gets the default FirebaseStorage instance.
  const storageRef = ref(normalStorage)
  const bucketPath = `personas-out/img-${cuid()}.jpg`

  const bucket = defaultStorage.bucket();
  // const bucketRef = bucket.ref(); // Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'Bucket'.ts(2339)

  const metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
  };

  const imageRef = ref(storageRef, bucketPath);
  const file = new File([url], bucketPath, {
    type: "image/jpeg",
  });
  // will happen in the background?
  uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, file, metadata)
    .then((snapshot: any) => {
      console.log('Uploaded', snapshot);
    });

  return bucketPath
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to use the Firebase client SDK (`firebase/storage`) in nodejs code.  The client SDKs are meant to work in a browser only.  For nodejs code that runs on a backend (which is what you're doing when you deploy to Cloud Functions), you should use the Firebase Admin SDK.  The [API it exposes for Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) is essentially a thin wrapper around the [Google Cloud Storage nodejs library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest).

Comment: heya this did help me figure it out, tx. But is it not possible to use the 'web' SDK from node/server side? It does seem to have more API functions. Does it depend on some DOM or other client side APIs?

Comment: You can find out by looking at the source code. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk